# Android non-latin letters conversion

Tags: android, non-latin, latin

I have search in the ListView. When I insert Latin letters, I need the result returned in cyrilic utf-8. I've been thinking about catching all letters and converting them to Cyrillic but there are 31 letters. Is there a simple way to do this in android, and can anybody give me an example how is done?

Example Listview:

- Здраво
- Чао
- Пример
- Тест

When i type Test what i mean in cyrilic utf is Teст and the result will be Тест